# How to restore my backup to a different database?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a backup and I want it to restore it to a new
Database  Wss_Content3 
The backfile is a backup of the Wss_Content database.

When I run the following code:

```
USE Master;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Wss_Content3 FROM DISK = 'f:\Fill_Wss_Content.bak'
  WITH 
  MOVE 'Wss_Content3' TO 'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content3.mdf',
---------------------------------------^^^^^
  MOVE 'Wss_Content3_log' TO 'F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content3_log.ldf';
```

I get:

> Msg 1834, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The file
>   'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content.mdf' cannot be
>   overwritten.  It is being used by database 'WSS_Content'. Msg 3156,
>   Level 16, State 4, Line 3 File 'WSS_Content' cannot be restored to
>   'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content.mdf'. Use WITH
>   MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. Msg 1834, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 3 The file
>   'F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content_log.ldf' cannot
>   be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'WSS_Content'. Msg 3156,
>   Level 16, State 4, Line 3 File 'WSS_Content_log' cannot be restored to
>   'F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content_log.ldf'. Use
>   WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file. Msg 3119, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 3 Problems were identified while planning for the
>   RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details. Msg 3013, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 3 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

It's like to restore on the database Wss_Content but I want to do it on a new database Wss_Content3.

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**
With:

```
USE Master;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Wss_Content3 FROM DISK = 'f:\Fill_Wss_Content.bak'
  WITH 
  MOVE 'Wss_Content' TO 'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content3.mdf',
---------------------------------------^^^^^
  MOVE 'Wss_Content_log' TO 'F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content3_log.ldf';
```

I get:

```
Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Wss_Content3' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

**EDIT2:**

```
USE Master;
GO
RESTORE  FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'f:\Fill_Wss_Content.bak'

WSS_Content E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content.mdf D   PRIMARY 163158360064    35184372080640  1   0   0   140B6DD4-DCA0-4FD8-BA65-59390D5FC3B5    0   0   162484191232    512 1   NULL    133075000000938400215   F50C4B9C-B575-4158-B5D6-F44B92FE0380    0   1   NULL
WSS_Content_log F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\WSS_Content_log.ldf L   NULL    22918791168 2199023255552   2   0   0   C83B63C2-B68E-4101-A52B-07EFC08446D7    0   0   0   512 0   NULL    0   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000    0   1   NULL
```

**EDIT3:**
I've tried this (with Wss_Content5.mdf and Wss_Content5_log.ldf
) non existing:

```
RESTORE   DATABASE Wss_Content3 FROM DISK = 'f:\Fill_Wss_Content.bak'
  WITH 
  MOVE 'Wss_Content' TO 'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content5.mdf',
---------------------------------------^^^^^
  MOVE 'Wss_Content_log' TO 'F:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content5_log.ldf
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Wss_Content3' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Try remove the 3 from the logical name . MOVE 'Wss_Content' TO .... and the 'Wss_Content_log' also

Comment: Squirrel, I have tried what you suggest. In edit you see the error

Comment: Sounds like your database has more than two files, but you're only using `WITH MOVE` for two of them. You need to move *all* of the files when restoring a copy to the same instance. You can use `RESTORE ... WITH FILELISTONLY;` to see which files exist in the backup.

Comment: do a RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'f:\Fill_Wss_Content.bak' to view what is the logical name. And then use it in the WITH MOVE part accordingly

Comment: Ok Squirrel and Aaron Bertrand I did that and it seems that the files I use are fine.

Comment: check that the files does not exists "E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content3.mdf' if it does, restore to a different name

Comment: Squirrel even changing to a diffrent name I get an error (see edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the following option:

```
WITH REPLACE
```

If you're using the wizard from SQL Management Studio to restore the database rather than the command line, there is a corresponding option that needs to be checked: "Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)"

Comment: If I use replace will 'E:\MSSQL\MSSQL11.SHP2013PROD\MSSQL\Data\Wss_Content.mdf' be replaced? Wss_Content cannot be replaced. I need both db Wss_Content e Wss_Content3 in the same instance

Comment: What that directive means is "It's OK to overwrite the destination database with a backup which is not from this database"

Comment: I guess I can accept your answer as I did it with the wizard but I checked replace

Comment: I always use the wizard too ;)